# iis 7.0 Internal 500 Error

Tags: iis-7, .net-4.0

i am tearing my hair out.

I have read every post on the internet and cannot for the life of me figure out HOW to force IIS 7.0 on 2008 to display detailed errors.

I have published a .net 4.0 app.

i am at a complete loss. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've turned off "friendly errors" in your client as well...

Comment: thanks.. first thing i read about.. turned off. still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this lots of times.
Here is my command line code to turn display errors then turn them back off after I've fixed it.

```
set Website=Mywebsite.com
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%Website%" -section:system.webServer/httpErrors  /errormode:"Detailed" /commit:apphost

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%Website%" -section:system.webServer/asp /scriptErrorSentToBrowser:"true" /commit:apphost

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe STOP SITE /site.name:"%Website%"
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe START SITE /site.name:"%Website%"

pause

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "%Website%" -section:system.webServer/httpErrors  /errormode:"DetailedLocalOnly" /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe STOP SITE /site.name:"%Website%"
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe START SITE /site.name:"%Website%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try : Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager -> Default We Site -> Click Error Pages properties and select Detail errors